# What is the usage and difference between hibernate,spring and struts?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

I know that Hibernate,Struts and Spring is popular java frameworks now a days.

I want to know that what is the difference between them and what is the usage of these frameworks in context of java application.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, and/or unclear. If you can edit it to make it a *specific* question with a hard-and-fast answer not based on opinion, that would be a fit for SO's Q&A format. If not, probably best to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Hibernate is an object-relational mapping solution for persisting objects in a relational database.
2. Spring is a framework based on dependency injection, aspect-oriented programming, and libraries for persistence, remoting, messaging, web mvc, etc.  It started in 2001 as an alternative to EJBs; it had a strong influence on the EJB3 spec.
3. Struts was the original Java web MVC framework built on servlets and JSPs.

Spring is larger than both Hibernate and Struts.  It can use either, but it has other alternatives for ORM and web MVC.